# Connecting to an existing RabbitMQ Queue exclusively

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, message-queue, easynetq

I have a worker that subscribes to a pre-existing queue on rabbitmq. For redundancy purposes, we decided to add another worker that connects to the same queue.

Is it possible to have a set-up where the first worker acquires an exclusive connection to the queue so that the second worker will not be able to dequeue messages and thus acting as a standby worker?

Comment: So basically you want that only 1 consumer is consuming the queue at any given moment?

Comment: Yes, with a Worker as fail over

Answer (score 0):

Well... When you declare a queue, you can set the `exclusive` flag. That give "access rights" only to the client that declared it.

In your case the queue already exists, so you can't declare it again with setting the `exclusive` flag to true (I'm assuming that since the queue is pre-created for someone else to consume, this flag is false).

There are few solutions, considering that you want only one consumer at a time (I didn't ask why must it be one).
One would be that you have some sort of consumer watchdog that would be spawning the consumers and making sure that only one is alive at a single moment. Actually - it would monitor just the one consumer and restart it if it's blocked or dies...

You could also try something with [consumer priorities](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-priority.html) and tweak the consumer(s) in such way that the priority consumer has a bigger prefetch, but I don't think it could be suited to what you need.